# How can I highlight subset of values in ggplot2 plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, highlight, subset

For example I have basic stacked plot:

`ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=factor(color),fill=factor(cut)))+geom_bar(position="fill")`

and I have small subset diamonds with "carat" value higher than 3:

```
subset(diamonds,carat>3)
```

and I want to highlight this particular values on plot (like points or labels if our diamonds would have IDs) to see in which part of distribution are they lying. Is there any possibility to do something like that?

PS: unfortunantly I`m not allowed to post figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following inserts the count of "carat greater than 3" into the bar segments. I've broken the problem down to a number of steps. Step 1: New variable identifying "carat greater than 3". Step 2: Get a summary table of the counts - of diamonds for each color and cut, and of "carat greater than 3' for each color and cut. I used the ddply() function from the plyr packages. Step 3: The bar plot without the labels. Step 4: Add to the summary table a variable giving the y positions of the labels. Step 5: Add the geom_text layer to the plot. The data frame for geom_text is the summary table. geom_text() needs aesthetics for label (in this case, the count for "carat greater than 3'), y position (calculated in the previous step), and x positions (color).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

# Step 1
diamonds$caratGT3 = ifelse(diamonds$carat > 3, 1, 0)

# Step 2
diamonds2 = ddply(diamonds, .(color, cut), summarize, CountGT3 = sum(caratGT3))
diamonds2$Count = count(diamonds, .(color, cut))[,3]
diamonds2

# Step 3
p = ggplot() + geom_bar(data = diamonds, aes(x=factor(color),fill=factor(cut)))

# Step 4
diamonds2 <- ddply(diamonds2,.(color), 
        function(x) { 
          x$cfreq <- cumsum(x$Count) 
          x$pos <- (c(0,x$cfreq[-nrow(x)]) + x$cfreq) / 2 
          x 
        }) 

# Step 5
(p  <- p + geom_text(data = diamonds2, 
   aes(x = factor(color), y = pos, label = CountGT3),
   size = 3, colour = "black", face = "bold"))
```

[image]